# Two tables. One contains the school info and the other personal. A quire that picks students who are from CA and like either skateboard or soccer.

Tags: mysql, database, datatable, union, cloud9

[image]

[image]

[image]

What currently happens is it just selects students from CA and students who like to skateboard. I need it to return only students who are both from CA and play soccer.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You have to make some effort. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   schooldata a
       INNER JOIN studentinfo b
               ON b.schooldata_id = a.id
WHERE  a.state = "ca"
       AND ( activity = "soccer"
              OR activity = "skateboard" )
```

You will have to do inner join based on lastname and firstname column ex:-b.lastname=a.lastname and b.firstname=a.firstname . ideally you should be maintaining primary key column of type integer in schooldata table and its foreign key reference in studentinfo and join based on those columns.

Answer (score -1):

You should use join clauses. And I think base on your question. Inner Join is the best clause you should use.

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;